# Changing the background theme of the Forget Password page in Lightning Communities

Tags: community, lightning

I am trying to customize the branding colour or background image of the change password page of the lightning community, under this address /_ui/system/security/ChangePassword .

It looks like might be a simple thing, but I am not able to find where I can change it as I can't find it in Salesforce document as well.

Any suggestion would be really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there are not much you can do about the standard Change Password page. Salesforce applies the Branding rules to login page, but not the change password page.

However there is an alternative

- Build your own Lightning component for changing password
- Create a Lightning page using Community Builder and add your component
- Under Login and Administration setting on Community Management, selected newly created Community builder page.

Let me know if you still need any further clarifications.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you think I can copy and paste the default template from Salesforce in Lightning community and modify the css, then in the community manager select the page I have created. Haven't tried it just want to know it whether it is possible in the easiest way.

Comment: What do you mean by copying the default template? Lightning builder will automatically use the template selected  for your community.

Comment: cool, i was actually just thinking is there anything else that i need to be aware if I want to create my own Forget Password page but reuse the codes of the default Forget Password Page. From your answer I think i can just use it but tweak the css a bit. thx.

Comment: I have never implemented a custom Password Change for Lighting communities, so give it a try. Feel free to post your questions, if you face any issues :) Also post your answer here to help others.